# How to correctly format XML for iOS parsing

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I am in the process of writing some code to parse questions into objects.  I am using NSXMLParser.  The problem is, I also formatted my own XML data, and I think it is incorrect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<factor value="1">
    <key value="plus">
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>

    </key>
    <key value="minus">
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>

    </key>
</factor>
<factor value="2">
    <key value="plus">
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
    </key>
    <key value="minus">
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
        <question>PLACEHOLDER_TEXT</question>
    </key>
</factor>
```

That is the xml im am parsing.  Halfway through the questions, the parser gives me 
`Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"`

My Question: How can I format this so that the entire document is parsed correctly.  The end result is to have a question managed object with attributes of:key, and factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting all your `<factor>` into a root tag called `<factors>` so you can iterate over it to get all your `<factor>`

Comment: does that need any special formatting? I tried that by enclosing it in <container> </container> but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two root elements, `<factor>`.  A well-formed XML document can only have one root element.